# Moment: add +1 Month when formatting the Date

Tags: typescript, momentjs

Months in `MomentJs` are 0-based. January is the month 0 and december is the month 11. How can I format the date with an elegant way with the correct value of the month?

For example:

```
// date is 10.January.2020
moment(date).format('DDmmYYYY')
// output: 10002020 but I want to get 10012020
```

Comment: month aren't 'MM' ? 'mm' are the minutes

Comment: and they are 1-based, as usual : 
https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

Comment: You get "Deprecation warning: value provided is not in a recognized RFC2822 or ISO format" which you should not ignore.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Months in format specifier 'MM' are 1 based, as usual.

You mix them with minutes 'mm', which are probably zero if you use a "date-only" value.

Docs here : https://momentjscom.readthedocs.io/en/latest/moment/04-displaying/01-format/

```
moment(date).format('DDMMYYYY')
```

Comment: you are right, I used minutes (mm) instead of Months (MM)

Comment: Man you wrote it almost at the same moment as I did!

Answer (score 1):

Exactly like that except months are "MM" and not "mm".

```
moment(date).format(DDMMYYYY); => 10012020
```